# Limiting the docker daemon CPU resource

Tags: docker, cpu-usage, docker-machine

When I do `docker info` it gives me the following result:

```
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.632 GiB
```

but I want the cpu to be 1 and not 2.How do I restrict the CPU for the docker itself?

Answer (score 1):

On windows, open up powershell and type

```
# turn off all wsl instances such as docker-desktop
wsl --shutdown
notepad "$env:USERPROFILE/.wslconfig"
```

Edit `.wslconfig` file with notepad and write down these settings:

```
[wsl2]
memory=3GB   # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 up to 3GB
processors=2 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
```

type `wsl` in powershell

restart docker

type `docker info` and you should see something like

```
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 6.789GiB
```

Credits to Ali Bahraminezhad, check out his post [here](https://itnext.io/wsl2-tips-limit-cpu-memory-when-using-docker-c022535faf6f)

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#cpu) you can limit the container resources usage by specifying the `--cpus` flag when running.
The docker info command is returning the number of cpus on the machine.

To limit the container to use only one cpus use the following:

```
docker run --cpus="1" ...
```

Comment: yes i have used it for the container in the run command,but I want to restrict it for the machine itself.

Answer (score -1):

Yo can limit resources to docker using docker machine. In other words you can limit resources assigned to virtual machine itself from your VM provider itself.

To create a new docker machine and specify its configurations:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-cpu-count=2 --virtualbox-disk-size=50000 nameOfYourMachine
```

To modify current one you can use `VBoxManage` that comes with `Virtualbox`, stop VM first, change settings and start it again.

```
docker-machine stop
VBoxManage modifyvm default --cpus 1
VBoxManage modifyvm default --memory 4096
docker-machine start
```

In Mac or windows where you have GUI, you can easily limit the docker resources CPU/memory from Preferences or Settings menu as shown below.

[image]

Comment: NO,docker is running on rhel and it has no GUI.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can limit resources to your docker machine